# Bootstrap Checkbox Switch Background color issue during disable

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

These bootstrap checkboxes are without disable:

[image]

These bootstrap checkboxes are disabled:

[image]

During Disable state it changes background color but I don't want to change background color i want as it is in the disabled state so how can I do this?

I already trying to override default class but nothing change.

This is the default CSS from bootstrap

```
.switch input:disabled + span {
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

I want to remove this background color!!

Comment: `background-color: transparent;`? If it doesn't override, its probaly because the css from bootstrap is loaded later then your custom CSS. You can allways do `background-color: transparent !important;` though.

Comment: actually, i want the same color as switch are not in disable

Comment: or i want same background effect in disable state

Comment: background-color: #fff;

Comment: if my checked switch color is #2196F3 then in diable state I want the same color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I Got The Answer:

```
.switch input:checked:disabled + span {
    background-color:#5d9cec;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
.switch input:not(:checked):disabled + span {
    background-color:#fff;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Ty @Lalit for Helping Me

Answer (score 1):

Please check the answer, this is I did using bootstrap default classes and css provided in your question and make out the difference what you are doing wrong.

**AS IT SEEMS WORKING FOR ME**

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.switch input:disabled + span {
    background-color:#2196F3;
    cursor: not-allowed;
opacity: 0.6;
}
.switch input:not(:checked):disabled + span {
    background-color:#ccc;
    cursor: not-allowed;
opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked disabled="disabled">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: if it is checked and disable at that time same background color?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" checked disabled="disabled"> Yes please see this like it is checked and disabled at the same time

Comment: I want same this color  #2196F3 in disable state

Comment: please check now
.switch input:disabled + span {
    background-color:#2196F3;
    cursor: not-allowed;
opacity: 0.6;
}

Comment: or you can remove the opacity as well to have the same color

Comment: if it is not checked and disable then? actually, i also want if a switch is not checked n disable than I want not disable switch color

Comment: Please check now

Comment: now its working!! Thank You So Much @Lalit Sachdeva +1 i post my ans because i want only this two css thats why i dont need this another stuff from yr ans

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer for Bootstrap v4.5.0 in 2020

```css
/* Enabled */
.custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before
{
  border-color: red !important;
  background-color: blue !important;
}

/* Disabled */
.custom-control-input:checked:disabled~.custom-control-label::before
{
  border-color: yellow !important;
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

`!important` is necessary if you want to overwrite all inputs with class `custom-control-input`. If you just need to overwrite one, try changing the `.custom-control-input` bit to an ID like `#yourinputid`

Answer (score 0):

Please provide us with some of your css code. Regarding your issue, bootstrap css is often selected with high specificity, you might want to make sure specificity of your selectors is higher.